# Swiper - Prevent multi swipe

Tags: javascript, swipe, swiper.js, slide

In swiper (Swiper Element) it is possible to swipe really fast,
so that event *slideNextTransitionStart* is **triggered twice** before *slideNextTransitionEnd* is called or finished executing.

How can I prevent that, so that the next slideNextTransitionStart can only be triggered again when slideNextTransitionEnd has finished?

Thank you very much.